# Understanding HoldFirst in QuickSort algorithm

Tags: recursion, hold

I have read the implementation of QuickSort algorithm in WL from Roman Maeder's *Computer Science with Mathematica* (2000).

The implementation is shown below.

```
SetAttributes[swap, {HoldFirst}]
swap[l_, i_, j_] := ({l[[i]], l[[j]]} = {l[[j]], l[[i]]}; l);

SetAttributes[QSort, HoldFirst]
QuickSort[list_] := Module[{l = list}, QSort[l, 1, Length[l]]; l];
QSort[l_, n0_, n1_] /; n0 >= n1 := l;
QSort[l_, n0_, n1_] := 
 Module[{lm = l[[Floor[(n0 + n1)/2]]], i = n0, j = n1},
  While[ True, 
   While[l[[i]] < lm, i++];
   While[l[[j]] > lm, j--];
   If[i >= j, Break[]];
   swap[l, i, j];
   i++; j--];
  QSort[l , n0, i - 1];
  QSort[l, j + 1, n1]
  ]
```

My question is why should we use `HoldFirst`? Is it because we are modifying the argument `l` and this is not allowed in the WL?

Comment: Try implementing this without the HoldFirst attribute and see what happens. You get error messages because 'l' evaluates to a list of numbers, and you can't use a Part assignment with a list, only with a symbol. (The error messages link you to the documentation page - the blue icon at the right.) The held argument remains a symbol so the remaining code can function as desired. The default behavior unheld behavior is "smart pass by value", so you are essentially making a copy and modifying parts of the copy.

Comment: Many thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. I should've said that trying to use Set (=) with a list is where the problem lies; Part doesn't care.

Comment: To answer the last question, yes, it is exactly so `l` can be modified in place. This is implicit in the remarks already made but should be stated explicitly. Effectively the `Hold*` attributes, used in this way, provide a "call-by-reference" capability.

Comment: Thank you is much. Much appreciated.